# Python NameError: global name 'assertEqual' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm following Learn Python the Hard Way and I'm on Exercise 47 - Automated Testing (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex47.html)

I am using Python3 (vs the book's use of Python 2.x) and I realize that assert_equals (which is used in the book) is deprecated. I am using assertEqual.

I am trying to build a test case but for some reason, when using nosetests in cmd, I get the error: `NameError: global name 'assertEqual' is not defined`

Here is the code:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room



def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom",
        """ This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
            door to the north. """)
    assertEqual(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assertEqual(gold.paths, {})

def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")

    center.add_paths({'north': north, 'south': south})
    assertEqual(center.go('north'), north)
    assertEqual(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here. You can go east.")
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here. You can go up.")

    start.add_paths({'west': west, 'down': down})
    west.add_paths({'east': start})
    down.add_paths({'up': start})

    assertEqual(start.go('west'), west)
    assertEqual(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
    assertEqual(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

I've tried searching GitHub for any solutions, and I'm just not sure why it's giving me the NameError and how would I go about fixing it.

Comment: Isn't `assertEqual` part of unittest? nose still uses `assert_equal`.

Comment: Wow you're right. I just changed `assertEqual` to `assert_equal` like you stated and it works flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Had a similar problem with the second module in a python selenium test script. Solved it by including 'self.' before the 'assertIn'.

Before:

```
assertIn('images/checkbox-checked.png', ET)
```

After:

```
self.assertIn('images/checkbox-checked.png', webelement)
```

Answer (score 5):

assertEqual is a method of `unittest.TestCase` class, so you can only use it on objects that inherit from that class.   Check [the unittest documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html).

Comment: exactly the reason for the NameError.  nose.tools have no assertEqual function

Comment: Sure, but answering a question by pointing to the docs for a library he's not using instead of pointing to the docs for the library he's using strikes me as somewhat backwards...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [assertEqual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) in python 3 with the help of [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) Library.

```
import unittest

class TestBalanceCheck(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self,sol):
        self.assertEqual(sol('[](){([[[]]])}('),False)
        self.assertEqual(sol('[{{{(())}}}]((()))'),True)
        self.assertEqual(sol('[[[]])]'),False)
        print('ALL TEST CASES PASSED')
    
t = TestBalanceCheck()
t.test(balance_check)`
```

Make sure `assertEqual` is inside `unittest.Testcase`

Answer (score 1):

### Why there is `NameError`?

Because `nose.tools` haven't got `assertEqual()` method. Possibly, you are mixing `nose.tools` with `unittest`.

### How to avoid it in your case?

As someone said *(in comments)* `nose` has got `assert_equal`:

```py
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room

def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom",
        """ This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
            door to the north. """)
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, {})
```

But, officially it **is deprecated.** Any usage of it causes [`DeprecationWarning`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040166/python-3-3-deprecationwarning-when-using-nose-tools-assert-equals):

```
...
Asserts something ...
.../test.py:123:    
DeprecationWarning: Please use assertEqual instead.
  assert_equals(a, b)
ok
...
```

---

So, you should use `assertEqual` from [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html):

```py
import unittest
from ex47.game import Room

class TestGame(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_room(self):
        gold = Room("GoldRoom",
            """ This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north. """)
        self.assertEqual(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
        self.assertEqual(gold.paths, {})
```

[Read the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)