# Python 3.3: DeprecationWarning when using nose.tools.assert_equals

Tags: python, deprecated, python-3.3, nose, python-unittest

I am using nosetest tools for asserting a python [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html):

```python
...
from nose.tools import assert_equals, assert_almost_equal

class TestPolycircles(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.latitude = 32.074322
        self.longitude = 34.792081
        self.radius_meters = 100
        self.number_of_vertices = 36
        self.vertices = polycircles.circle(latitude=self.latitude,
                                           longitude=self.longitude,
                                           radius=self.radius_meters,
                                           number_of_vertices=self.number_of_vertices)

    def test_number_of_vertices(self):
        """Asserts that the number of vertices in the approximation polygon
        matches the input."""
        assert_equals(len(self.vertices), self.number_of_vertices)

    ...
```

When I run `python setup.py test`, I get a deprecation warning:

```
...
Asserts that the number of vertices in the approximation polygon ...
/Users/adamatan/personal/polycircles/polycircles/test/test_polycircles.py:22:    
DeprecationWarning: Please use assertEqual instead.
  assert_equals(len(self.vertices), self.number_of_vertices)
ok
...
```

I could not find any `assertEqual` in nose tools. Where is this warning coming from, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `nose.tools` `assert_*` functions are just automatically created PEP8 *aliases* for the `TestCase` methods, so `assert_equals` is the same as `TestCase.assertEquals()`.

However, the latter was only ever an *alias* for `TestCase.assertEqual()` (note: *no trailing `s`*). The warning is meant to tell you that instead of `TestCase.assertEquals()` you need to use `TestCase.assertEqual()` as the [alias has been deprecated](http://bugs.python.org/issue9424).

For `nose.tools` that translates into using `assert_equal` (no trailing `s`):

```
from nose.tools import assert_equal, assert_almost_equal

def test_number_of_vertices(self):
    """Asserts that the number of vertices in the approximation polygon
    matches the input."""
    assert_equal(len(self.vertices), self.number_of_vertices)
```

Had you used `assert_almost_equals` (with trailing `s`), you'd have seen a similar warning to use `assertAlmostEqual`, as well.